# Typerror (Singleton array...) when using train_test_split within a custom class

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn

> TypeError: Singleton array array(<__main__.AZHU_EmailClassifier_2
> object at 0x000001D6E7A680D0>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a
> valid collection.

I get this error when I try to run the train_test_split function within my custom AZHU_EmailClassifier_2 class.

My class:

```
class AZHU_EmailClassifier_2:
    import os
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def retrain_model(self, csv_file):
        
        MIN_ROW_NUMBER = 500
        TEST_SIZE = 0.25
        RANDOM_STATE = 42
        
        self.os.chdir(r"c:\LORI\PROJECTS\ALLIANZ\INCOMING_CHANNELS") # <---- a retraining file mappaja
        
        df=self.pd.read_excel(csv_file,error_bad_lines=False, header=None)
        
        df.dropna(axis=0,how='any', inplace=True)
             
        rows_no=df.shape[0]
        if rows_no<MIN_ROW_NUMBER:
            print("Insufficient number of rows (<35.000)! RETRAINING ABORTED")
            return None

        X=df[0]
        y=df[1]
        
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=self.train_test_split(X,y)
        #X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=self.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=TEST_SIZE, random_state=RANDOM_STATE, stratify=y)
        
        return X_train
```

The error is triggered when I run the train_test_split function.

The whole error message:

> --------------------------------------------------------------------------- TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call
> last)  in 
> 1 instance = AZHU_EmailClassifier_2()
> 2
> ----> 3 instance.retrain_model("retraining_dummy.xlsx")
>
> in retrain_model(self, csv_file)
> 28         y=df[1]
> 29
> ---> 30         X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=self.train_test_split(X,y)
> 31         #X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test=self.train_test_split(X,y,test_size=TEST_SIZE,
> random_state=RANDOM_STATE, stratify=y)
> 32
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\model_selection_split.py in
> train_test_split(*arrays, **options)    2125         raise
> TypeError("Invalid parameters passed: %s" % str(options))    2126
> -> 2127     arrays = indexable(*arrays)    2128     2129     n_samples = _num_samples(arrays[0])
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> indexable(*iterables)
> 291     """
> 292     result = [_make_indexable(X) for X in iterables]
> --> 293     check_consistent_length(*result)
> 294     return result
> 295
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> check_consistent_length(*arrays)
> 251     """
> 252
> --> 253     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
> 254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
> 255     if len(uniques) > 1:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> (.0)
> 251     """
> 252
> --> 253     lengths = [_num_samples(X) for X in arrays if X is not None]
> 254     uniques = np.unique(lengths)
> 255     if len(uniques) > 1:
>
> ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in
> _num_samples(x)
> 194     if hasattr(x, 'shape') and x.shape is not None:
> 195         if len(x.shape) == 0:
> --> 196             raise TypeError("Singleton array %r cannot be considered"
> 197                             " a valid collection." % x)
> 198         # Check that shape is returning an integer or default to len
>
> TypeError: Singleton array array(<**main**.AZHU_EmailClassifier_2
> object at 0x000001D6E7A68F10>,
> dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.

I have no clue why does it throw this error. Could you please point me in the right direction? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You got this error because you import `train_test_split` inside the class, therefore, `train_test_split` becomes a bound method rather than a function, and the instance will be passed as the first argument whenever the method is called. Here is an minimum example that can reconstruct the situation

```
class test():
    
    from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
    
    def retrain_model(self):
        print(self.train_test_split)
        print(self.train_test_split())
    
test_instance = test()
test_instance.retrain_model()
```

After you run this script, you will got an `TypeError`

```
TypeError: Singleton array array(<__main__.test object at 0x7ffa473ae438>, dtype=object) cannot be considered a valid collection.
```

while the location of `self.train_test_split` in memory is also `0x7ffa473ae438`.

According to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/)

> Imports are always put at the top of the file, just after any module
> comments and docstrings, and before module globals and constants.

Therefore, the simplest solution is to import everything outside the class and call `train_test_split` directly

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

class AZHU_EmailClassifier_2():

    def __init__(self):
        pass
    
    def retrain_model(self,):
        
        MIN_ROW_NUMBER = 20
        TEST_SIZE = 0.25
        RANDOM_STATE = 42
                
        df = pd.DataFrame({0:np.linspace(1,100,100),1:np.random.rand(100)})
        X=df[0];y=df[1]
        X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=TEST_SIZE,random_state=RANDOM_STATE)
        
        return X_train

test = AZHU_EmailClassifier_2()
test.retrain_model()
```

Comment: Thank you! This is answer is perfect. I have not been aware of this but learned it well! Thank you!